# Correctly accessing entire row for database insertion with mysqli & PHP

Tags: php, database, session, mysqli

I'm working on a project where we are sending messages to users using a database. In this php file, I insert into the database with a to, from, date, and message field. The goal is to send the same message to all the people within one certain company. However, when I try sending it, the message will not send sometimes, and when it does, it will only message the first contact in the group/row that I get from the database. I've seen other examples online, but so far I haven't seen this exact problem with anyone else. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
$sql = 'SELECT drivers.username FROM project.drivers WHERE drivers.sponsor="'.$_SESSION["company"].'"'; //query to get all driver usernames within one company
$result = $conn->query($sql);
//$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ //iterating throughout all the drivers
    $to  = $row["username"]; //username of current driver
    $from = $_SESSION["username"]; //from current company
    $message = $_SESSION["username"] . " updated your point to dollar ratio. Your new point to dollar ratio is " . $_SESSION["pointRatio"] . "."; //message
    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO project.messages(messages.date, messages.to, messages.from, messages.message) VALUES(now(), '".$to."', '".$from."', '".$message."')"; //inserting message into database
    $conn->query($sql2); //query for database
    $to  = $_SESSION["username"]; //this is the same format but sending the message to the company itself
    $message = $_SESSION["username"] . " updated your point to dollar ratio. Your new point to dollar ratio is " . $_SESSION["pointRatio"] . ".";
    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO project.messages(messages.date, messages.to, messages.from, messages.message) VALUES(now(), '".$to."', '".$from."', '".$message."')";
    $conn->query($sql2);
}
```

Comment: Your code is a huge security risk!! You are vulnerable for sql-injection. Please read upon this and do the required steps to prevent it!!!!

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out, but I wasn't too concerned about it because it isn't for any commercial use. Just focused on learning more about mysqli and php, although I can definitely go back and fix it.

Comment: Well when you are just about learning and training it is as important as if it would be for any (non-) commercial use. Your goal shouldn't be fixing it only for this question, but learn how to do it the right way. This knowledge will be helpful all the way you go with sql.

Comment: What is the definition of the `messages` table - are there any unique constraints?

Comment: You're 100% right and I appreciate the advice. It's definitely something I will come back to, I was just stuck on this particular problem.

Comment: You are selecting ONE column `drivers.username` but expecting to be returned many other columns?????

Comment: **Error checking** but if you cannot be bothered, Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`

Comment: Do your column names **really** have dots in them?

Comment: @NigelRen No unique constraints for messages.

Comment: If you do `SELECT * FROM` does it work better?

Comment: @RiggsFolly They are called exactly like that in other code sections with no issue, and using var dump as suggested below does call every variable I need. I believe there is just something wrong with the insert.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Unfortunately no. Also I'm still learning, but doesn't that basically call all the columns? I don't think I need that. Unless I'm mistaken.

Answer (score -1):

if you add var_dump and check records from database - are correct? Do you really get all rows?

```
$sql = 'SELECT drivers.username FROM project.drivers WHERE drivers.sponsor="'.$_SESSION["company"].'"'; //query to get all driver usernames within one company
$result = $conn->query($sql);
//$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ //iterating throughout all the drivers
    var_dump($row);
}
```

Comment: Checking it out in mysql workbench gives me all the rows, and using var dump gives me all of them too. That's part of what is stumping me.

Comment: OK - if you have all results try next thing - inside while display text of your sql inserts - are all correct?

Comment: Still all correct. Every value in the row is called, the text for the sql insert is correct. It's just like insert I've done in other sections of my code. Is it something with the query call perhaps?

Comment: So in project.messages is same number of new records as number of $row? If the numbers match - isn't your problem in another part of your code?